# Cannot type into an editor in a xul panel

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

the **Cannot type into an editor in a xul panel** is a known [bug in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385609).

I simply want to reuse my code from my google chrome extension by hosting a webapp online and including it in the extension both google chrome and firefox by using a popup window.

This is how I include the webapp

```
<popupset id="mainPopupSet">
    <menupopup id="smsflatrate-popup">
        <iframe height="500px" src="http://webapp.mysite.net/" 
                flex="1" type="content-primary"/>                           
    </menupopup>    
</popupset>
```

The problem is, it is possible to focus input elements but the input fields do not react on key-events, so no input can be provided.

[It seems that there is some kind of solution for this problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385609), but I think I do not really understand what to do here.

E.g. from the link above, what would be a solution according to this post?

```
There are many ways to display HTML in a XUL UI:
1) including HTML inline in the XUL document. This should work fine everywhere,
including in panels.
2) include an HTML IFRAME in the XUL document. This currently works fine
everywhere, except that IF the iframe is in a panel, there are some problems
with focus. This bug is about that one issue.
3) instead of a panel, you can create a XUL window using window.open that
contains HTML inline or in an IFRAME, and everything should work.

Having said that, if I open this bug's testcase in a Firefox trunk build, I
*can* tab into the textbox and type into it, so it looks like focus is
basically working now? The problem is that I can't focus the textbox by
clicking on it. In fact, if you click on the arrow to do a search, you navigate
to a new page where there is a textbox that you *can* click to focus.

So I think we have here just some simple bug that's preventing click-to-focus
from working, sometimes. Enn, can you look into that?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that given the list of suggestions your best choice is to open a new window to represent your popup. You can make it look like a popup by setting its position, turning off OS crhome, etc.